# Re-Enable Mouse Scroll in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been tinkering with the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrjackess/pen/rOJLGN). It prevents the user from scrolling down the page, instead using the downward scroll to form a constellation animation. How would I allow the user to be able to scroll down the page after the constellation animation is complete? As it currently stands, scrolling is disabled irregardless of the state of the animation.

This is an excerpt of the code that I am struggling with.

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {

  var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
  var delta = Math.max(-30, Math.min(60, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

  if (delta > 0) {
    showFinal=false;
    for(var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      stars[i].reseting = true;
    }
  } else {
    showFinal=true;
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].move();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
function keyDown(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;

  if (keyCode==38) {
    //up
    showFinal = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      stars[i].reseting = true;
    }
  } 

  if (keyCode==40) {
    //down
    showFinal = true;
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].move();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well that is something I won't recommend doing but here are the 2 changes you need to do

```
#container {
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

and remove `e.preventDefault();` from the `function MouseWheelHandler(e) {` you would need to add some more text in the body to see the scrolling.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way I could change the image that the constellation generates without changing every single coordinate?

Comment: The image that the constellation generates depends on the coordinates that are assigned to the stars/dots and you have to relocate them to the new position that would form the image/shape you desire. the method `this.move()` is related to the  initial and final shapes if you look closely the `else` part of the first `if(!showFinal) {` belongs to the final shape i.e `//go to final position
   this.x += ((this.pos.x+screenOffset)-this.x)/this.s.animSpeed;
   this.y += ((this.pos.y)-this.y)/this.s.animSpeed;` you need to relocate these two axis to the shape you want.

Comment: I see that, but it would be rather tedious to re-assign every coordinate manually. Is there a way of generating an array of coordinates based on an image and then I could simply copy and paste those new coordinates. For example, I was looking at https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/OMPgNE where the image is converted to particles, but there is no output that displays each individual coordinate and there are too many pixels to use all of them. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Disable scrolling:

```
$('#container').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Enable scrolling:

```
$('#container').css('overflow', 'scroll');
```